# Probability of an event in relationship with a certain geometrical representation

Tags: probability, trigonometry, geometric-probability

A recent post (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1979286) asked the following question [in substance: I have slightly modified it]: "What is the probability of the event

$$\tag{1}\cos(\theta_1)+\cos(\theta_2)+\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)+1 \leq 0 $$

given that $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are independent, uniformly distributed random variables on $[0,2\pi)$"?

I gave an answer relying on a geometrical interpretation. While elaborating this answer, at a certain step, I made an error, and replaced, in (1), the constant term $+1$ by $-1$. Surprisingly, the unfavorable regions of the square $[0,2\pi) \times [0,2\pi)$, appeared as the interiors of four truncated elliptical regions as displayed on the bottom figure  (obtained by Geogebra).

My question is therefore twofold:

1) What is the probability of the event

$$\tag{2}\cos(\theta_1)+\cos(\theta_2)+\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)-1 \leq 0 ? $$

with $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ independent, uniformly distributed random variables on $[0,2\pi)$?

2) Why are these frontier curves elliptical, with puzzling equation for the "mother"-ellipse centered in $0$:

$$(\theta_1)^2+(\theta_2)^2-\theta_1\theta_2=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 \ \ ?$$

the other ones being translated from this one.

**Remark about question 1:**  this probability  can hopefully be obtained using a different (non geometrical) approach.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shapes in your probability graph are not ellipses. (They just look very close.)

Let us start from

$$\cos(\theta_1)+\cos(\theta_2)+\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)-1 = 0 $$

Apply the substitution $y=\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{\sqrt2}$ and $x=\frac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{\sqrt2}$ which is a rotation by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to better orientation your pseudo-ellipses:

$$\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{y-x}{\sqrt2}\right)+\cos\left(\sqrt2x\right)-1=0$$

Using sums to products:

$$2\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\cos(\sqrt{2}x)-1=0$$

This can be solved for $y$:

$$y=\sqrt{2}\arccos\left(\frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{2}x)}{2\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right)$$

$$y=\sqrt{2}\arccos\left(\frac{2\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{2\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right)$$

$$y=\sqrt{2}\arccos\left(\sin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\tan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$

Visually this looks similar to a half-ellipse.
[image]

Some calculations give a y-intercept of $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$ and an x-intercepts of $\pm\sqrt{2}\arctan(\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5}))$. Plotting an ellipse with these values for the two radii looks basically the same.
[image]

However plotting the difference shows that they are not equal.
[image]

Using the above formula for the curve rather than the ellipse gives a slightly different area:

$$4\sqrt{2}\int_0^{\sqrt{2}\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5}}))}\ \arccos\left(\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\tan\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\ dx$$

The integral isn't exact so using Wolfram and dividing by $4\pi^2$ gives the proportion: [$0.2261376180596750632\cdots$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%204*sqrt(2)%2F(4pi%5E2)*arccos%20(sin(x%2Fsqrt(2))tan(x%2Fsqrt(2)))%20for%200%3Cx%3C2sqrt(2)arctan(sqrt(sqrt(5)-2))

So the probability is: $0.7738623819403249367\cdots$

Comment: @JeanMarie - Yes I know your next question - why are they so close. At this point I'm not sure.

Comment: +1 This explains the small error compared to Monte Carlo when the elliptic equation is used.

Comment: Thanks. I was pleased your simulation answer was there to compare with.

Comment: Very accurate answer ! Thank you very much (from my mobile).

Answer (score 3):

$$(\theta_1)^2+(\theta_2)^2-\theta_1\theta_2=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2$$
can be written as
$$\frac{(\theta_1+\theta_2)^2}{4}+\frac{(\theta_1-\theta_2)^2}{\frac{4}3}=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2$$
by changing the coordinate sytem
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\theta_1+\theta_2)
\\ 
y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\theta_1-\theta_2)
\end{matrix}\right.$$
it becomes
$$\frac{x^2}{\frac{\pi^2}{2}}+\frac{y^2}{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}=1$$
which is a standard ellipse whose area is

$$A=\pi(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}})(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}})$$

Due to symmetry, the four unfavorable regions constitute a single ellipse. So the undesired region is $A$.
The desired probability is therefore $$\frac{4\pi^2-\sqrt{3}\pi^3/6}{4\pi^2}=1-\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{24}\approx 0.7733$$

Using Monte-Carlo method

$$
\bbox[0.5em,#efe,border:0.1em groove navy]{\
\Pr(\cos(\theta_1)+\cos(\theta_2)+\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)-1 \leq 0) \approx 
 0.7738}
$$

So considering the other answer, there would be an error of the order of $10^{-4}$ by assuming elliptic boundaries.

[image]

I used the following Matlab code for the Monte-Carlo simulation

```
n=1e6;
t1=rand(1,n)*2*pi;
t2=rand(1,n)*2*pi;
f=cos(t1)+cos(t2)+cos(t1-t2)-1;
p=mean(f<0);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the third line be $$\frac{(\theta_1+\theta_2)^2}{\pi^2}+\frac{(\theta_1-\theta_2)^2}{\frac{\pi^2}{\color{red}{3}}}=1$$

Comment: Thank you @IanMiller, I added the change of coordinate equations.

Comment: I'm still stuck on how to do the second part.

Comment: The second part? do you mean the Monte-Carlo @IanMiller?

Comment: The why the two functions give the same graph. $$(\theta_1)^2+(\theta_2)^2-\theta_1\theta_2=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2$$ $$\cos(\theta_1)+\cos(\theta_2)+\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)-1=0$$

Comment: Very interesting "enquiry", complementary to Ian Miller's work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help @JeanMarie.